# How to update multiple rows in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I would like to update existing records in a table where `userID` and where `classID`.

```
$users = User::all(); //Get all users;

$userClasses = UserClass::whereIn('classID', 'users->class_id)
                        ->whereIn('userID', 'users->id)
                        ->update('role' => 3);
```

But I get error `Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.`
I know it is because $users is a collection of object and that is why it returns this error. But What is the best way to achieve this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

- `$users` is a Collection. If you want all the ids get them through a Collection method like pluck.
- `update('role' => 3)` is invalid syntax. It should be `update(['role' => 3])`

```
UserClass::whereIn('classID', $users->pluck('class_id')->all())
         ->whereIn('userID', $users->pluck('id')->all())
         ->update(['role' => 3]);
```

Comment: thank you for taking time to answer this. I also want the classID in users table not only user id.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few typos in your code:

```
$users = User::all(); 
$userClasses = UserClass::whereIn('classID', $users->class_id)
                    ->whereIn('userID', $users->is)
                    ->update(['role' => 3]);
```

And with the collection, you need to iterate through it for update

```
foreach($users as $user){
    $userClasses = UserClass::whereIn('classID', $user->class_id)
                    ->whereIn('userID', $user->is)
                    ->update(['role' => 3]);
}
```

Comment: is your class id not present in the user collection because you write this '$users->class_id'.

Answer (score 0):

if you have 3 tables (user, class, user_class) table and the user belong to a class then in that case create a function in the

`public function class() { return $this->belongsTo(Class::class); }`

```
$userClasses = UserClass::whereIn('classID', $user->class->class_id)
                ->whereIn('userID', $user->is)
                ->update(['role' => 3]);
```

with `$user->class` you have collection again use pluck if user belong with multiple classes other vise use 'hasone Relationship' in the user class